# How to pass another entire column as argument to pandas fillna()

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I would like to fill missing values in one column with values from another column, using `fillna` method.

(I read that looping through each row would be very bad practice and that it would be better to do everything in one go but I could not find out how to do it with `fillna`.)

Data before:

```
Day  Cat1  Cat2
1    cat   mouse
2    dog   elephant
3    cat   giraf
4    NaN   ant
```

Data after:

```
Day  Cat1  Cat2
1    cat   mouse
2    dog   elephant
3    cat   giraf
4    ant   ant
```

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You can provide this column to `fillna` (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html)), it will use those values on matching indexes to fill:

```
In [17]: df['Cat1'].fillna(df['Cat2'])
Out[17]:
0    cat
1    dog
2    cat
3    ant
Name: Cat1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice! I did not know that ``fillna`` takes a series.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the serie had to be the exact size of the number of NA values.

Comment: It works also for dataframes for multicolumnar rows. That feature of fillna is very helpful.

Comment: This is not working for me, it still gives `NaN`

Answer (score 30):

You could do

```
df.Cat1 = np.where(df.Cat1.isnull(), df.Cat2, df.Cat1)
```

The overall construct on the RHS uses [the ternary pattern from the `pandas` cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) (which it pays to read in any case). It's a vector version of `a? b: c`.

Comment: Not the solution I used for this problem but very interesting pattern! Thanks!

Comment: is there a way of using this for multiple columns?
e.g. if this df had cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4,cat5 and let's say cat5 was empty. would there be a way to fill cat5 with values from cat1 if cat1 empty then cat2, if cat2 empty then cat3 etc.?

Comment: @user8322222 I am definitely late but if anybody is having this question, you can do nested np.where, just like you would do in excel cell = np.where(cond, val_true, np.where(cond, val_true, val_false),).

Comment: You want to mention that this is just redefining the pandas builtin `pd.DataFrame.fillna()`. And I suspect the corner-case behavior may differ  e.g. for mismatched series lengths from different dataframes: dfA['Cat1'], dfB['Cat2']

Comment: Pandas can do this itself: `df['Cat1'].mask(df['Cat1'].isnull(), df['Cat2'])`. (I'm not sure if `.mask()` existed when this answer was posted.) But yeah, it's even simpler to use `.fillna()`.

Answer (score 15):

Just use the `value` parameter instead of `method`:

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
  Cat1      Cat2  Day
0  cat     mouse    1
1  dog  elephant    2
2  cat     giraf    3
3  NaN       ant    4

In [21]: df.Cat1 = df.Cat1.fillna(value=df.Cat2)

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
  Cat1      Cat2  Day
0  cat     mouse    1
1  dog  elephant    2
2  cat     giraf    3
3  ant       ant    4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What does it change to use value rather than the method described by joris?

Comment: @xav `value` is the first parameter, so joris is actually doing the exact same thing. As he said, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Comment: Yes, the docstring is a bit misleading as `method` is listed there first.

Answer (score 10):

[pandas.DataFrame.combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) also works.

(**Attention: since "Result index columns will be the union of the respective indexes and columns", you should check the index and columns are matched.**)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["1","cat","mouse"],
    ["2","dog","elephant"],
    ["3","cat","giraf"],
    ["4",np.nan,"ant"]],columns=["Day","Cat1","Cat2"])

In: df["Cat1"].combine_first(df["Cat2"])
Out: 
0    cat
1    dog
2    cat
3    ant
Name: Cat1, dtype: object
```

Compare with other answers:

```
%timeit df["Cat1"].combine_first(df["Cat2"])
181 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit df['Cat1'].fillna(df['Cat2'])
253 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.where(df.Cat1.isnull(), df.Cat2, df.Cat1)
88.1 µs ± 793 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I didn't use this method below:

```
def is_missing(Cat1,Cat2):    
    if np.isnan(Cat1):        
        return Cat2
    else:
        return Cat1

df['Cat1'] = df.apply(lambda x: is_missing(x['Cat1'],x['Cat2']),axis=1)
```

because it will raise an Exception:

```
TypeError: ("ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''", 'occurred at index 0')
```

which means np.isnan can be applied to NumPy arrays of native dtype (such as np.float64),
but raises TypeError when applied to **object** arrays.

So I revise the method:

```
def is_missing(Cat1,Cat2):    
    if pd.isnull(Cat1):        
        return Cat2
    else:
        return Cat1

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: is_missing(x['Cat1'],x['Cat2']),axis=1)
701 µs ± 7.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
In [8]: df.assign(Cat1=df['Cat1'].mask(df['Cat1'].isna(), df['Cat2']))
Out[8]: 
   Day Cat1      Cat2
0    1  cat     mouse
1    2  dog  elephant
2    3  cat     giraf
3    4  ant       ant
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general approach (fillna method is probably better)

```
def is_missing(Cat1,Cat2):    
    if np.isnan(Cat1):        
        return Cat2
    else:
        return Cat1

df['Cat1'] = df.apply(lambda x: is_missing(x['Cat1'],x['Cat2']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had a need for doing something similar recently.  I was able to use the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["1","cat","mouse"],
    ["2","dog","elephant"],
    ["3","cat","giraf"],
    ["4",np.nan,"ant"]],columns=["Day","Cat1","Cat2"])

print(df)

  Day Cat1      Cat2
0   1  cat     mouse
1   2  dog  elephant
2   3  cat     giraf
3   4  NaN       ant

df1 = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 1]
df1 = df1.to_frame()
print(df1)
```

Which yields:

```
  Cat1
0  cat
1  dog
2  cat
3  ant
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!