# Scala - Fill "null" column with another column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to replicate the [problem mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357276/pandas-fillna-with-another-column) in Scala DataFrames. I have tried using the following approaches, to no success so far.

Input

```
Col1  Col2
A       M
B       K
null    S
```

Expected Output

```
Col1  Col2
A       M
B       K
S <---- S
```

Approach 1

```
val output = df.na.fill("A", Seq("col1"))
```

The `fill` method does not take a column as the (first) input.

Approach 2

```
val output = df.where(df.col("col1").isNull)
```

I cannot find a suitable method to call after I have identified the null values.

Approach 3

```
val output = df.dtypes.map(column =>
  column._2 match {
    case "null" => (column._2 -> 0)
  }).toMap
```

I get a `StringType` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `when/otherwise`, as shown below:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("A", "M"), ("B", "K"), (null, "S")
).toDF("Col1", "Col2")

df.withColumn("Col1", when($"Col1".isNull, $"Col2").otherwise($"Col1")).show
// +----+----+
// |Col1|Col2|
// +----+----+
// |   A|   M|
// |   B|   K|
// |   S|   S|
// +----+----+
```

Comment: I get "cannot resolve the symbol when". Do this require any special import? @leo-c

Comment: @smaug, you'd need a couple of `import`s, as shown in the revised answer.