# Assign value to a dataframe column based on another column and condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
id,col1,col2
```

now for records where col1 is empty, I need to copy value of col2 into col1. how to do this?
below is what I tried but it is not working.

```
df[df[col1]==''] = df['col2']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass another entire column as argument to pandas fillna()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357276/how-to-pass-another-entire-column-as-argument-to-pandas-fillna)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using if else condition. If col1 is empty then fill col2.

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col2'] if row['col1'] == '' else row['col1'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are close,

```
mask = (df['col1']=='') 
# mask = df[col1].isnull() # if you are looking for Nan/null values instead of empty strings
df.loc[mask, 'col1'] = df.loc[mask, 'col2']
```

Comment: This is actually not a good approach. You should always use `loc` to assign to a slice in a DataFrame. By chaining the slicers (`df['col1'][mask]`) you risk having a copy as intermediate which won't be updated. See [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/16343464)

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the suggestion, updated my answer to use `loc`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to slice your column of interest:

```
df.loc[df['col1']=='', 'col1'] = df['col2']
```

If your indices are unique, pandas will align the right-hand side automatically.

If the indices are not unique, you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['col1']==''
df.loc[m, 'col1'] = df.loc[m, 'col2']
```

Or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1']=='', df['col2'])
```